# Cannot import a Module from Models into admin.py which are in the same folder

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

I am following a tutorial exactly step-by-step, and it is not working for me.

In a Django application, I am trying to import a Post class from the Models.py file, into the admin.py file.

Here is admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register (Post)
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
my-project
   manage.py
   blog
      __init__.py
      admin.py
      models.py
```

I have tried to cd my Python terminal into various directories and nothing works. I also tried different syntaxes.

I keep getting each time:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Please show full traceback. Did you try ```from blog.models import Post```?

Comment: Strangely, running the server (manage.py runserver) works fine. But running the admin.py script alone, gives the ImportError. I thought that the server would not run, but it does... any idea why one works and the other doesn't? @BiploveLamichhane

Comment: probably there is a circular dependency issue in the models